# User has roles for systems - how to (object-)model ternary relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've got the following Entities:

```
Privilege ( Id, Name )
Role ( Id, Name, ICollection<Privilege> )
System ( Id, Name )

User ( Id, Name, Pass, ? )
```

Now I want to model "A user may have for each of zero or more systems zero or more roles", e.g.:

```
IDictionary<System, ICollection<Role>> SystemRoles { get; set; }
```

Is this possible with ASP.NET EntityFramework? If yes, how? What attributes do I have to set?

Been looking around for quite some time now, however I don't find anything useful on the net for "entity framework code first ternary relation"

Can you point me to some nice link where this is covered in detail? Or maybe give me a hint how to model it / which attributes I can put on the dictionary?

Additional question: If the IDictionary solution works somehow, is there any change to get change tracking proxy performance? IDictionary is not an ICollection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A user may have for each of zero or more systems zero or more roles

You will need an entity that describes the relationship between the three:

```
public class UserSystemRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int SystemId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public System System { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I would create a composite primary key from all three properties because each combination may only occur once and must the unique. Each part of the key is a foreign key for the respective navigation property `User`, `System` and `Role`.

Then the other entities would have collections refering to this "link entity":

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<UserSystemRole> UserSystemRoles { get; set; }
}

public class System
{
    public int SystemId { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<UserSystemRole> UserSystemRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<UserSystemRole> UserSystemRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And then the mapping with Fluent API would look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSystemRole>()
    .HasKey(usr => new { usr.UserId, usr.SystemId, usr.RoleId });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserSystemRole>()
    .HasRequired(usr => usr.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.UserSystemRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(usr => usr.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserSystemRole>()
    .HasRequired(usr => usr.System)
    .WithMany(s => s.UserSystemRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(usr => usr.SystemId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserSystemRole>()
    .HasRequired(usr => usr.Role)
    .WithMany(r => r.UserSystemRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(usr => usr.RoleId);
```

You can remove one of the collection properties if you don't need them (use `WithMany()` without parameter then).

**Edit**

In order to get a dictionary for a user you could introduce a helper property (readonly and not mapped to the database) like so:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<UserSystemRole> UserSystemRoles { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<System, IEnumerable<Role>> SystemRoles
    {
        get
        {
            return UserSystemRoles
                .GroupBy(usr => usr.System)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(usr => usr.Role));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to load the `UserSystemRoles` property with eager loading first before you can access this dictionary. Or alternatively mark the `UserSystemRoles` property as `virtual` to enable lazy loading.

Comment: a) So there is no way to do this without a in-between class? b) I'm new to EF, is it necessary to have UserId and User in the in-between class? Isn't it enough to just have User there?

Comment: @D.R.: (a) No. Just take the viewpoint of a database schema. You need such a table with the three Id columns to describe the relationship, hence you need such an entity. (b) Well, you could work without the foreign key property `UserId`, but you will have to invent an alternative primary key property then, like just an autoincremented `Id`. In my opinion the "triple key" is better because it will be unique automatically. From business perspective it makes no sense to allow duplicates of the combination of those three columns.

Comment: @D.R.: About the dictionary I have added an Edit section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the helper property! Regarding a) I know how the DB should look in the end, I thought EF is going to support me more and is creating the in-between table behind the scenes. b) Same here: Why can't I put the foreign key constraints directly on the objects? Why do I have to use the Ids? Can't EF figure out that itself?

Comment: @D.R.: (a) EF isn't helping more in this scenario. The only situation where you don't need an entity for a table is the link table of a many-to-many relationship. But that's a "binary" relationship joining only *two* other entities. For anything else you need a dedicated link entity in your model. (b) You *can* put the FK constraints on the objects, but if you remove the `UserId` property from the `UserSystemRole` class what do you want to make the PK? It could only be a separate `Id` property and you'd have to ensure in business logic or with a constraint in the DB that the FKs are unique.

Comment: So it is not possible to construct the PK out of the three objects and EF figures out that only their IDs are necessary? Humpf : (

Comment: @D.R.: No, primary key properties must exist in the class and they must be primitive (`int`, `string`, etc.), they cannot be navigation properties.

Comment: Uh oh. Another question: You sure that the three modelBuilder.Entity/HasRequired/WithMany/HasForeignKey are required? Aren't they built by convention? At least it seems to work...do I miss something?

Comment: @D.R.: Yes, with those property names it works by convention. Only the `HasKey` is really required.