# asp.net 2 Properties refer same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one model class called Client.

```
namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Dispatch> dispatches { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have another class that has two properties with relationship to Client:

```
namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class Dispatch
    {
        public int DispatchId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int RecipientId { get; set; }

        public Client Customer { get; set; }
        public Client Recipient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In order to have a relationship in my Dispatch class I have to have clientId. Right? But in this case I will have two clientId. I am just started with ASP.NET MVC, and I can't understand it.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework here by any chance, it's really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you want to store two Entities in the same table? Customer and Recipient?

Comment: No you do not.  By having the reference to `Client`, that creates the reference for you (`Customer.ClientId` and `Recipient.ClientId`).  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: As @sgeddes said it is possible, but I would use inheritance in such a scenario.

Comment: For more information (irrespective of using inheritance or not) take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120085/user-has-roles-for-systems-how-to-object-model-ternary-relation.

Answer (score 0):

Because in my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Dispatch()
        {
            db.Dispatches.Include("Customer").ToList();
            db.Dispatches.Include("Recipient").ToList();
            var dispatch = db.Dispatches;

            return View(dispatch);
        }
```

And in my View I am trying to display:

```
@model IEnumerable<Logistic.Models.Dispatch>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dispatch";
}

<h2>Dispatch</h2>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <h2>Tracking : @item.TrackingId</h2> <br />
    <h2>Customer : @item.Customer.Name</h2> <br />
    <h2>Recipient : @item.Recipient.Name</h2> <br />
}
```

Comment: the first two lines of code in the controller method do not have any efect because they are not asigned to a variable. You need to remove them and modify the third line like this: `var dispatch = db.Dispatches.Include(d => d.Customer).Include(d => d.Recipient).ToList();`. Personally i prefer to use lambda expressions rather than magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to use RecipientId and CustomerId as Foreign Keys for Recipient and customer respectively? In this case you can add the foreign key attribute to the properties like this:

```
namespace Logistic.Models
{
    public class Dispatch
    {
        public int DispatchId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int RecipientId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Client Customer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RecipientId")]
        public Client Recipient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This will explicitly specify the foreign keys for the relationship. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 12:     <h2>Customer : @item.Customer.Name</h2> <br />

Comment: @Apprentice123456 Thats because the Customer for that item is null either because it does not exist in the DB or because the values have not been loaded. There are **two ways** to do this. 
1. You can make the Customer and Recipient virtual properties like this: `public virtual Client Customer {get; set;}` 
or
2. You can specify that you want those to be included when you query the db. For example: 
`Dispatch d = db.Dispatches.Include(d => d.Customer).First()`